# Multi story houses in terraria

Tags: terraria

How can I build houses on top of each other? I've seen people do it but the wiki says houses can't share doors or wooden platforms. What is the correct way to build multi story houses?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The generally accepted way is to stack rooms on top of each other, with doors leading out into a common vertical shaft of some kind.

Put the wooden platform floors out in the common areas so you can get around between the various rooms.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You want something similar to this:

[image]

Houses cannot share single tile walls either but they can share floor/ceilings as seen above.

Comment: Those rooms share a single floor/ceiling tile. Like Ziv, I've heard that you can't share single-tile walls for more than one room (for NPC moving in purposes). Does this screenshot mean that sharing a floor/ceiling tile is OK?

Comment: Yes you can share single tile ceilings and floors.